# A question on measuring weak non-compactness in $L_{1}(\mu)$ spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Let me first fix some notations. Let $X=L_{1}(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is a finite positive measure. Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $X$. Set

$\omega(A)=\inf\{\widehat{d}(A,K):\emptyset\neq K\subset X$ is weakly compact $\}.$ where $\widehat{d}(A,K)=\sup\{d(f,K):f\in A\}.$

O. F. K. Kalenda, H. Pfitzner and J. Spurny proved the following formula:
$$\omega(A)=\inf_{c>0}\sup_{f\in A}\int(|f|-c)^{+}d\mu$$
It is easy to verify that

$\int(|f|-c)^{+}d\mu=d(f,cB_{L_{\infty}(\mu)})$ for every $f\in X$ and every $c>0$.

Set 
$$\iota(A)=\sup\{\limsup_{n}\sup_{f\in A}|<x^{*}_{n},f>|:(x^{*}_{n})_{n}\in l^{w}_{1}(X^{*}),(x^{*}_{n})_{n}\subset B_{X^{*}}\}.$$
My question is:
$$\omega(A)\leq \iota(A)$$

The purpose of my question is to prove that $L_{1}$ has some quantitative Pelczynski's property $(V^{*})$.

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand the question, this inequality is wrong when $A$ is a singleton set, for then $\iota (A)= 0$.

Comment: If $A$ is a singleton set, then $\omega(A)=0$.  This is trivial.

Comment: I see.  I did not understand your definitions at first reading.

Comment: @BillJohnson,  can every $C_{0}(T)(T$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space) be written as the $c_{0}$-sum of a family of reflexive spaces $(X_{\gamma})_{\gamma}$?

Comment: Far from it.  If a $C_0(K)$ space can be so written, the $X_\gamma$ are all finite dimensional and uniformly injective and $C_0(K)$ is isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Look at the section on classical spaces in my Handbook "Basic Concepts" with Lindenstrauss.  There we define three parameters $a(K)$, $b(K)$, and $c(K)$ for a subset of $L_1$ and comment that they are equal (the gist of proving this is probably contained in the books of Albiac-Kalton and Wojtaszczyk).  I think it is easy to check that $c(K) =  \iota(K)$ and $a(K)= \omega(K)$.

Comment: I'll check them.

Comment: @BillJohnson, I can check that $a(K)=\omega(K)$ and $c(K)\leq ι(K)$. But I am not sure that $c(K)\geq ι(K)$. Could you give me a hint?